# PHP Form Script Security Issue

Tags: php, forms, security

I have a short php code to process a simple form. I want to make sure that the code is secure. I think it probably is secure but I am not 100% sure.

I am looking for some feedback so I can be sure the php is not vulnerable to attacks.

Here is the php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'someemail@some.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "someemail@some.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: secure from .... alien abduction?

Comment: If you want to validate an e-mail address, you should check out `filter_var()`.

Comment: @Dagon Other than alien abduction, I am also interested in preventing someone from hijacking the script and sending out spam from it and/or cross site scripting.

Comment: @JoeRay-The script seems have no control over the number of mails sent so anyone can send any no of mails from it ,Try limiting no of mails per IP for some specific time instead.

Comment: @Subhanker Limiting no of mails per IP for some specific time sounds great, I jus dont know how to do it. Can you pls post the code for that?

Comment: Do you have a database to store data ?

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, ask on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a style that I like to use for forms. I use error collection that stores all errors in an array and only progresses if it is empty.And you should not only try to attempt to stop injection attempts in the email field, you should validate and clean up any data you receive from a user

```
 <?php
    if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !="POST") || !isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
        $errors[]= "error; you need to submit the form!";
    }else{
        //Strip tags and slashes from the user input
        //If these fields are optional we will not produce an error if they're blank
        $name = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
        $visitor_email = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
        $message = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

        //Validate firs 
        if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)){
            $errors[]= "Name and email are mandatory!";
        }


        if(empty($errors)){
            if(IsInjected($visitor_email)){
                errors[]= "Bad email value!";
            }
            $email_from = 'someemail@some.com';//<== update the email address
            $email_subject = "New Form submission";
            $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n"."Here is the message:\n $message".

            $to = "someemail@some.com";//<== update the email address
            $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

            //Send the email!
            if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){
                //done. redirect to thank-you page.
                header('Location: thank-you.html');
            }else{
                $errors[]="Unable to send email";
            }
      }

 }//End of main block

 if(!empty(errors)){
    //Display errors to user
 }

 // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
 function IsInjected($str){
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
          '(\r+)',
          '(\t+)',
          '(%0A+)',
          '(%0D+)',
          '(%08+)',
          '(%09+)'
          );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
 }
```

?>

Comment: thanks for this, I tried the above code for some reason but didnt work, not sure why

Comment: what error did you receive? you can put 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your script to see errors.